Properly set up DNS records and use Application Load Balancer in AWS
I have an AWS EC2 instance that is only accessible within the VPC on the internal network. EC2 is running Dockerized Apache. Client requests are forwarded to the application load balancer internal-app-123456789.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com. A valid SSL/TLS certificate issued by an internal CA for the app.mydomain.tld domain has been imported into the AWS Certificate Manager.
The internal DNS record type A associates an IP address of EC2 instance, e.g. 111.222.333.444 to the domain app.mydomain.tld
app.mydomain.tld. IN A 111.222.333.444

The problem is that with that configuration it is not possible to access the server via HTTPS protocol, so https://app.mydomain.tld does not work. The same thing happens if I try to open the load balancer address internal-app-123456789.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com in the browser, I get an error page as seen in the screenshot.
Error page NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Do you think it would help to add a CNAME type record to the DNS that would look like this?
app.mydomain.tld. IN CNAME internal-app-123456789.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com

I do not use nor do I plan to for this project the AWS Route 53 DNS Service.
